# Time date comparsion in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have a table in my database that stores user input as a start date and end date after that, my users will have to select a time range and I have to display those records in the table that are within this time range?

Tried `stritotime();` and many other unctions but somehow I can't get the right results..

Any possible solution would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be with:

```
 SELECT count(*) FROM `table` 
 where 
 created_at>='2011-03-17 06:42:10' and created_at<='2011-03-17 06:42:50';
```

or use between:

```
  SELECT count(*) FROM `table` 
  where 
  created_at between '2011-03-17 06:42:10' and '2011-03-17 06:42:50';
```

it depends on your record what u want to display because i didnt see your table and an exemple what you you really to do so just change count(*) and get whatrecords you want.

EDIT:
if the users will select a range of time then they will be variables

then it will be something like that

```
   SELECT records FROM `table` 
   where 
  created_at >= '".$var_start_time."' and ended_at <= '".$var_end_time."';
```

Comment: When I take a better look at it I can understand the process.. I was having bad point of view .. I was trying to make the comparsion PHP side not in MySQL

Comment: i advice you to use PDO or mysqli instead not mysql

Comment: Yeah, I am USING PDO when i said MySQL it as in database context. But thanks anyways I will keep your note in mine(to be more concrete)

Answer (score 1):

you can use in mysql query BETWEEN ... AND ... comparasion operator
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: I am not using MYSQL to assign the dates I use user input in a text for (start/end)date like this: **12/12/2012** and have to compare it to `date("d/m/Y");`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this in your SQL, which is the recommended approach. If you have these start and end times stored in your database table as native DateTime types, for example, you can use your DBMS' Date functions to select the range as a UNIX timestamp (if that's what what you want).

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`start_time`), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`end_time`) FROM `table` WHERE `start_time` > INTERVAL -1 DAY AND `end_time` < NOW();
```

That's one example (assuming you're using MySQL) where you select all rows in the table where the column `start_time` is within the past 24 hours and the `end_time` column is up to the current server time.

To get the formatted date and then do the conversion to a UNIX time-stamp in PHP use:

```
SELECT `start_time`, `end_time` FROM `table` WHERE `start_time` > INTERVAL -1 DAY AND `end_time` < NOW();
```

and then in PHP you can do:

```
$result['start_time'] = strtotime($result['start_time']);
$result['end_time'] = strtotime($result['end_time']);
```

Keep in mind that strtotime expects the formatted date to comply with [PHP's date parsing rules found here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

P.S: The function in PHP you're looking for is [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) not stritotime.